# JQuery mobile. Only one https page on site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, https

As we know, JQuery mobile has problems with redirects from server.

What is the best way to have only one secured page on site?

Here is scenario:

1. User goes to root of site ->
2. User goes to payment page ->
3. <- Server redirects user to https payment page #On this step we can
   use **data-ajax=false**
4. User at payment page goes to any other page -> #We should have all
   links on page with **data-ajax=false**? Looks terrible. What is the proper
   way to get user out from this page to unsecured pages?

**UPD** This question is not only about mobile sites, it's about all sites, that use ajax intensively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to handle this is to detect the failed page load that is inherent to making a cross-domain AJAX call and attempt to change the protocols. AJAX and page transitions won't work using this approach, however, it prevents you from having to litter your site with `data-ajax=false` attributes. This works in both directions (i.e. both to and from HTTPS).

```
$(document).bind("pageloadfailed", function (event, data) {

    // Let the framework know we're going to handle things.
    event.preventDefault();

    // Attempt to change protocols
    window.location.href = data.absUrl.indexOf('https://') > -1 ?
        data.absUrl.replace('https://', 'http://') :
        data.absUrl.replace('http://', 'https://');

    // At some point, if the load fails, either in this
    // callback, or through some other async means, call
    // reject like this:
    data.deferred.reject(data.absUrl, data.options);

});
```

Comment: This is not perfect solution, because it causes two requests: 1st to https protocol -- send form data but cancelled (no response), 2nd --http -- produce response but doesnt send the data. FCK

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to set jQuery mobiles defaults. you can set jQuery to set all links to not ajax call. Therefore, you still have the look and feel of JQM with the function of a desktop website.
references to JQM setting defaults can be found at: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html